# Avoid creating duplicate Hyper-V switches

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to create a PowerShell script (for learning purposes if anything) to set up a virtual Hyper-V cluster from scratch using the new NanoServer. Its still in its early stages, and I'm learning PowerShell as I go as well. I'm running Windows 10 Pro.

When debugging I want to avoid creating Hyper-V switches if they already exist.

This is what I have currently:

```
$ethernet = Get-NetAdapter -Name ethernet
$wifi = Get-NetAdapter -Name wi-fi

New-VMSwitch -Name externalSwitch -NetAdapterName $ethernet.Name -AllowManagementOS $true -Notes 'Parent OS, VMs, LAN'
New-VMSwitch -Name WiFiExternalSwitch -NetAdapterName $wifi.Name -AllowManagementOS $true -Notes 'Parent OS, VMs, wifi'
New-VMSwitch -Name privateSwitch -SwitchType Private -Notes 'Internal VMs only'
New-VMSwitch -Name internalSwitch -SwitchType Internal -Notes 'Parent OS, and internal VMs'
```

The External switches don't get created again because that's not possible, so it errors out, but I get duplicates of the same private and internal switches if I run the New-VMSwitch commandlets again.

I've searched and tried several foreach and/or if constructions that I adapted from the internet, but I am so far unsuccessful or not getting the desired result.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do what you need it to:

```
If ( ! ( Get-VMSwitch | Where {$_.Name -eq "MySwitchName"} ) ) {
    New-VMSwitch -Name MySwitchName #-otherswitcheshere
}
```

Hope thig helps.

Ben

Comment: That works, but throw's an error when the switch does not yet exist. So I adjusted it a little: If ( ! ( Get-VMSwitch privateSwitch -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ) { New-VMSwitch -Name privateSwitch -SwitchType Private -Notes 'Internal VMs only' }

PS. Formatting in a comment is hard? I can't get the code block to show up like above...

Comment: Is there a better way to get around the error thrown when the switch doesn't exist yet?

Comment: See Updated Code - this gets all VMSwitches and then checks to see if one is called "MySwitchName" instead of attempting to get that switch directly by name.  If this has solved your problem, please upvote and/or accept my answer :)